# ESRI js API Print widget: how to get selected layout and format

Tags: typescript, api, printing, widget, arcgis-js-api

I am using the ESRI Print widget , is there any way to get selected layout and format when they are changed by the user ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you want to detect when the user change the values of layout and filter on the interface you will have to bind to the `change` event of the corresponding `select`. Assuming that the variable `print` has your `Print` widget, then something like this should work,

```
print.container.querySelector("select[data-target-property='layout']")
.on("change", event => console.log(`Layout: ${event.target.value}`));
print.container.querySelector("select[data-target-property='format']")
.on("change", event => console.log(`Layout: ${event.target.value}`));
```

I am assuming your widget is created and ready. In other case `print` or `print.container` or the result `querySelector` can be `null`.

If you just want to know those values when the user prints, then you can use the `submit` event or `completed` event like this,

```
print.on("submit", _ => {
    console.log(print.templateOptions);
});
```